# For instances of reference data, I would like to make the getters self replacing with the return value

Tags: performance, typescript, decorator, getter

My app loads instances of reference data. Some of the instances have getters that use data from other reference data. Like this:

```
class Person{
  name: string 
  cityId: number

  get city(): City {
    return City.all.get(this.cityId)!
  }
}
```

As the reference data never changes, a call to a getter will always return the same result. So I would like to make a getter that replaces itself with its result. I was thinking of a decorator like this:

```
export const selfReplacing = <T>(target: T, propertyKey: keyof T, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): any => {
  const oldGetter = descriptor.get!
  descriptor.get = function (this: T) {
    const value = oldGetter.call(this)
    Object.defineProperty(this, propertyKey, {
      value,
      enumerable: true
    })
    return value
  }
}
```

Which I could use like this:

```
class Person{
  name: string 
  cityId: number

  @selfReplacing
  get city(): City {
    return City.all.get(this.cityId)!
  }
}
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Redefining property descriptor on first property access is the best way to do that.

Alternatively, a value can be cached to local variable or, better, a property:

```
export const selfReplacing = <T>(target: T, propertyKey: keyof T, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): any => {
  const oldGetter = descriptor.get!
  const cacheKey = Symbol(`${propertyKey} cache`);
  descriptor.get = function (this: T) {
    if (!(cacheKey in this))
      this[cacheKey] = oldGetter.call(this);

    return return this[cacheKey];
  }
}
```

May be helpful if some caching strategy should be additionally implemented (cache expiration, etc).

Comment: Yes, that's an interesting solution too, especially in case of caching. That is not the case with me. I think replacing the getter with a value is much more performant, I think.

Comment: That's microoptimization because get accessor is very fast. But if you don't need to re-cache it then replacing a descriptor is reasonable.

Comment: That's a tough choice for me then about which implementation to take. I will anyway accept this answer. Thank you!